# datatrigger cannot set bound property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, triggers

I have 2 checkboxes (chkMfsUi and chkMfs). When I check chkMfsUi, I also want to check chkMfs (and disable it).

I tried it with a datatrigger:

```
        <Style x:Key="MfsCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkMfsUi}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And these are my checkboxes:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Name="chkMfsUi"
                Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
                Content="MFS - UI"
                IsChecked="{Binding MfsUi}"
                Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked" />
    <CheckBox Content="MFS" IsChecked="{Binding Mfs}" Style="{StaticResource MfsCheckBoxStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The IsEnabled property work fine, but the IsChecked doesn't. Maybe because it is bound? I am also using INotifyPropertyChanged with these properties.

If I set it in code behind, it works, but is it possible with a trigger though?

Regards,

Alfons

**EDIT:**

As appeared from the current answers, my question seems to be incomplete. I need to have the following three states:

[image: Possible states of the checkboxes]

AND last but not least: Both checkboxes' IsChecked properties must be bound! (This is the moment when the trouble comes in)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkMfsUi" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkMfs" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=chkMfsUi,Path=IsChecked}">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
```

**Another Method : By using style in resource**

Add this namespace first xmlns:Globalvaribale="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:Globalvaribale="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Window.Resources>
    <Globalvaribale:String x:Key="chkMfsUi">chkMfsUi</Globalvaribale:String>
    <Style x:Key="chkMfsstyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName={StaticResource chkMfsUi}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkMfsUi"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource chkMfsstyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Heena, your first method reacts not the way I want, when I click the second checkbox, but your second method does! So your second method is the correct answer! Thanks.

Comment: @ffonz You are most welcome.have you checked second method (using style).second method maybe work in your case.

Comment: Hi Heena, I'm sorry. I was too quick with my response. I noticed that your answer is too easy. Both checkboxes IsChecked properties aren't bound! And that is when the trouble comes in...

Comment: @ffonz its ok.But it should bind property.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the [`EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Represents a trigger that applies a set of actions in response to an event.

Example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked" SourceName="First">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Second"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">

                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked" SourceName="Second">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="First"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">

                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Unchecked" SourceName="First">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Second"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">

                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Unchecked" SourceName="Second">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="First"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">

                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>

    <CheckBox Name="First"
              Content="First" />

    <CheckBox Name="Second" 
              Content="Second" />
</StackPanel>
```

The `Storyboard`  can be stored in Resources for readability, like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FirstCheckedStory" ... />            
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked" SourceName="First">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FirstCheckedStory}" />
</EventTrigger>
```

Also, the `Storyboard` can contain several actions, just put him in order:

```
<Storyboard>
    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames ... />
    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames ... />
</Storyboard>
```